# accessing date in servlet from jsp

Tags: jsp, servlets

I should send a date type as a parameter from JSP to servlet so as to insert to MySQL database. When I use Date toDate = new java.sql.Date(format.parse(request.getParameter("to_date")).getTime()); in the servlet, it is always displaying 01 in the place of month.i am typing dates as 2013-03-03 but it was showing as 2013-01-03.please tell me where could be the mistake was?

Comment: How do you create **format**

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how you are definiting format, but it should be:

```
DateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
```

The string in the SimpleDateFormat constructor is case sensitive.